# Is there a way to express $n - i$ using division?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a way to express $n - i$ as a multiple of $n$, where $i$ and $n$ are integers? Like maybe $a/b(n)$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers?

Thanks.

Comment: What are these things ($n$, $i$, $a$, $b$) supposed to be - natural numbers? integers? complex numbers?

Comment: @Zev, fixed the ambiguity. Thanks! :)

Comment: Are you asking what you would have to multiply $n$ by to obtain $n-i$? If so, then a simple answer is that you can multiply $n$ by $\frac{n-i}{n}$ to obtain $n-i$. I'm not sure if that's addressing your question, though.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs I'm trying to get an expression that looks something like (n/(something)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of division does the trick.  I assume this is what you are looking for?

$n-i=n \left(1-\dfrac{i}{n} \right)$

$n-i=n \left( \dfrac{a}{b} \right)$

$n-i=\dfrac{n}{\left( \frac{b}{a} \right)}$

Where: $a=n-i$, $b=n$

Comment: Thanks Ryan, is there a way I can get the expression on the right to have n as the numerator?

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer.  This is the best identity I can think of.

Comment: That'll work! Thanks Ryan, you the man.